# How to implement one trait for different primitive types without code duplication?

Tags: rust, traits

I want to extend primitive numbers in Rust with a `floor_nearest` method which floors a number to the nearest multiple of another number e.g.:

```
let x = 3.7.floor_nearest(0.2);
assert_eq!(x, 3.6)
```

I want to implement this both for all integers and all floats. I have noticed the `num_traits` crate provides traits `Num`, `Float`, and `PrimInt`. Since the implementation for floats and integers are  different, I then set out to make a trait, `Rounder`, which I would then implement for each numerical trait:

```
pub trait Rounder
where
    Self: Num,
{
    fn floor_nearest(self, nearest: Self) -> Self;
}

impl<T> Rounder for T
where
    T: Float,
{
    fn floor_nearest(self, nearest: Self) -> Self {
        (self / nearest).floor() * nearest
    }
}

impl<T> Rounder for T
where
    T: PrimInt,
{
    fn floor_nearest(self, nearest: Self) -> Self {
        (self / nearest) * nearest
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `math::Rounder`
  --> src/math.rs:26:1
   |
17 | / impl<T> Rounder for T
18 | | where
19 | |     T: Float,
20 | | {
...  |
23 | |     }
24 | | }
   | |_- first implementation here
25 | 
26 | / impl<T> Rounder for T
27 | | where
28 | |     T: PrimInt,
29 | | {
...  |
32 | |     }
33 | | }
   | |_^ conflicting implementation
```

I understand the reason for this is technically that a struct could implement both "Float" and "PrimInt", however I know this to not be the case here.

How could I solve this in a sane way that will still allow me to use these implementations as method calls, without duplicating the same code twice for `f32` and f64``` and a number of times for the primitive integers?

Comment: I'd probably [just use a macro](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b99dd62e3217fa205655d9d60809955).

Comment: @eggyal should probably be an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 1):

You can use a macro to implement the trait for all number types:

```rust
macro_rules! impl_rounder_for_int {
    ($($t:ty),*) => {
        $(
            impl Rounder for $t {
                fn floor_nearest(self, nearest: Self) -> Self {
                    (self / nearest) * nearest
                }
            }
        )*
    };
}
impl_rounder_for_int!(i8, i16, i32, i64, i128, isize, u8, u16, u32, u64, u128, usize);

macro_rules! impl_rounder_for_float {
    ($($t:ty),*) => {
        $(
            impl Rounder for $t {
                fn floor_nearest(self, nearest: Self) -> Self {
                    (self / nearest).floor() * nearest
                }
            }
        )*
    };
}
impl_rounder_for_float!(f32, f64);
```

You can make the macro more compact (as @eggyal suggested), however I feel this is a good middle ground between readability and compactness.